# How to production deploy NativeScript Native App OTA bypassing the AppStore or PlayStore?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After a user installs an NativeScript Native app in their mobile, we do not want the user to manually keep looking for updates in the Appstore or Playstore. Instead, we (developers/enterprise) want the ability to push updates over the air (ota) to these NativeScript Native app.

***Does NativeScript(Angular2) have a feature/support for dynamic update experience like this ReactNative component from microsoft*** (https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push)

Answer (score 0):

This has been in the [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/issues/247) but, not yet available in the existing version